# Getting "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" exception when validating the URL

Tags: c#, ssl, .net-4.5, tls1.2, windows-server-2012-r2

I am trying to validate URL in C# code and I am facing  error on Windows server 2012R2 server machine

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

I have checked the multiple solutions found/got via various posts in net and nothing resolved this.

C# code

```
public static bool isBrokenLink(string url, string KBid)
{
    Boolean isBrokenLink = false;
    try
    {
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        webRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        webRequest.Timeout = 40000;
        using (HttpWebResponse httpresponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            if (httpresponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                isBrokenLink = false;
            }
            else if (httpresponse.StatusCode >= HttpStatusCode.Ambiguous && httpresponse.StatusCode <= HttpStatusCode.RedirectKeepVerb)
            {
                isBrokenLink = false;
            }
            else
            {

                isBrokenLink = true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        isBrokenLink = true;

    }
    return isBrokenLink;

}
```

On the machine, I have installed both IE and Chrome browser. When I trying to load the URL in IE 11 browser, I am getting the same error.

When trying to check in the chrome browser with the URL, it works fine. I also tried to set the default browser as chrome in my machine and checked. But still the same issue. Does anybody know about this issue?

Can we modify the code to consider the chrome browser for HttpWebResponse validation?

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons for this kind of error and the provided details are not sufficient. Typical problems are with validating certificates or with TLS versions or with supported ciphers etc.

In general: your C# code and IE use the same TLS stack built into Windows while Chrome comes with its own TLS stack (BoringSSL). Setting Chrome is default browser will not magically replace the OS TLS stack, i.e. it will still only used by Chrome and not your C# program.

If the URL is public you can use [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) to get more information about this site which also displays typical problems and compatibility with various kind of clients. This might help you to narrow down the problem yourself.